# Склонение названий произведений, состоящих из нескольких фраз

Tags: согласование, склонение, названия

Когда возникает необходимость согласовать название произведения (книги, фильма), склонение обычно допускается при отсутствии родового понятия и номинативном характере названия:

- *Сегодня в "Известиях" опубликовали мой репортаж."*
- *В "Крестном отце" показана идеализированная жизнь членов мафии.*
- *Он мог обосновать любую идею через аналогию с "Русланом и Людмилой".*

Конечно, если название является полным предложением, то оно обычно не склоняется:

*Вчера с детьми были на "Как Иванушка-дурачок за чудом ходил"*.

Но как быть при наличии нескольких предложений в названии? Например, сегодня я хотел сослаться на словарь под названием "Новый словарь русского языка. Толково-словообразовательный". Для этого я выбрал конструкцию: *Например, в "<название здесь>"*.

И я уже просклонял первую часть, но уперся в точку. Должна ли склоняться вторая фраза названия?

*Например, в "Новом словаре русского языка. Толково-словообразовательный"* воспринимается несогласованно.

*Например, в "Новом словаре русского языка. Толково-словообразовательном"* воспринимается не как название с номинативным субназванием, а как название с неполным предложением.

Аналогичный вопрос возникает касательно названий с двоеточием:

*В "Экономической реформе: опыт, проблемы, трудности"* или *в "Экономической реформе: опыте, проблемах, трудностях"*?

Ну и уж совсем напоследок — пары альтернативных названий:

*В "Похождениях Чичикова, или Мёртвые души"* или *в "Похождениях Чичикова, или Мёртвых душах"*?

Answer (score 1):

В таких конструкциях обычно употребляют родовое слово:

Например, в словаре-справочнике такого-то автора "Новый словарь русского языка. Толково-словообразовательный"...

Возможное выражение:

> ...в "Похождениях Чичикова, или Мёртвых душах"

Но с родовым словом будет читабельней, приятней для глаза. Почему не хотите его употребить - экономия средств или просто лень?

Answer (score 0):

> ...Допускается при отсутствии родового понятия и номинативном характере названия

Здесь и ответ. Если вторая часть тоже номинативная, то её надо склонять.

> Новом словаре русского языка. Толково-словообразовательный"

Только не это. Название в котором склоняется только первая часть выглядит совершенно противоестественно.

А вот если почему-либо не хочется (допускаю, что ваш случай как раз их таких),  то приходиться или по совету бежать за родовым словом, или же что вернее, сокращать название до одного предложения. Еще вариант - дать название в скобках:

***В "Новом словаре русского языка"

В "Новом словаре русского языка..."

В словаре Имярекова "Новый словарь русского языка. Толково-словообразовательный"

В словаре Имярекова ("Новый словарь русского языка. Толково-словообразовательный")***

Все варианты годятся, но **это именно на тот, случай, когда склонять обе части названия не хочется**.

*Маленькое замечание.* На самом деле, тут сложность только с понятием "номинативный". Совсем недавно не очень успешно пытался выяснить у Людмилы, как она понимает отличия его от неполного. Ваши примеры (типа "Как Иванушка-дурачок за чудом ходил") явно не номинативные. И в туже корзинку. Пример Людмилы *"Похождениях Чичикова, или Мёртвых душах"* тоже не соответствует формальным условиям. Не знаю, признает ли Людмила вторую часть ("Мертвые души") номинативной (где та самая "бытийность"?!), но в любом случае тут не точка стоит между составляющими, а запятая и союз, что и приводит к относительной легкости склонения обеих частей.